# How to customise two different powers at the same time

Tags: macros, shortcut, definition

Is it possible to define shorthand for a definition as follows:

```
\def\par#1{\frac{x_{#1}}{y^{#1}}}
```

In the document I have

```
\par1 + \par2 + \par3
```

whereas for `\par2` and `\par3` this is expected outcome, for `\par1` it is unpleasant to see `\frac{x_{1}}{y^{1}}` instead of `\frac{x_{1}}{y}`. How can I overcome this

Comment: always use `\newcommand` not `\def`.  `\def` gives no warning if, as here, you over-write a core tex feature and completely break latex. If you redefine `\par`, _Nothing_ will work in LaTeX.

Comment: You chose the worst possible name for your macro. It is the command to end  paragraphs!  It is not usually seen because almost always you can substitute it by a  blank line, leaving the text more readable, but internally the blank line is a \par.

Answer (score 2):

If the input is always numeric, you can use `\unless\ifnum#1=1` as a test:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand\Bpow[1]
  {%
    \frac{x_{#1}}{y\unless\ifnum#1=1^{#1}\fi}
  }

\begin{document}
$\Bpow{1} + \Bpow{2} + \Bpow{3}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Adding a second variant which supports an optional argument for the index of the numerator, defaulting to the same value as the mandatory argument.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Bpow[2][\Bpow@tmp]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \def\Bpow@tmp{#2}% will only have this meaning until \endgroup
      \frac{x_{#1}}{y\unless\ifnum#2=1^{#2}\fi}
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\Bpow{1} + \Bpow[1]{2} + \Bpow{3}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: One more question: in this example if I want to write `x_1/y^2`, `x_2/y^3` and so on do I have to define `\newcommand\Bpow[1][2] ` and give them differently to numerator and denominator?

Comment: @Boogeyman see my edit.